Cannot find module 'swiper/css' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)
I'm trying to use Swiper but I'm getting this error 'Cannot find module 'swiper/css' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)'
Here are the files and codes:
import { useState } from 'react';
import { type Swiper as SwiperTypes } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/thumbs';
import { Navigation, Thumbs } from 'swiper/modules';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import taNaCestaImage from '../../../assets/images/tanacesta.png';
import styles from './Projects.module.scss';
const Projects: React.FC = () => {
    const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState<SwiperTypes | null>(null);

    return <section className={`${styles.projectsSlides} container bg-black text-white bg-opacity-50 rounded-5`}>
        <div className='row p-5'>
            <Swiper
                modules={[Thumbs]}
                thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null }}
                slidesPerView={1}
                scrollbar={false}
                navigation={false}
                allowTouchMove={false}
            >
                <SwiperSlide>
                    <div className='row row-cols-2'>
                        <img src={taNaCestaImage} alt='Ta na Cesta - Hortifruti' />
                        <article>
                           ...
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>
                    <div className='row row-cols-2'>
                        <img src={taNaCestaImage} alt='Ta na Cesta - Hortifruti' />
                        <article>
                           ...
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
            <Swiper
                slidesPerView={3}
                modules={[Thumbs, Navigation]}
                watchSlidesProgress
                onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
                navigation={true}
                className={`${styles.projectsSlides__slide_thumb}`}
            >
                <SwiperSlide>
                    ...
                </SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>
                    ...
                </SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
    </section>
}

export default Projects;

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "auto",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2023"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

vite.config.ts
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@swiper': './node_modules/swiper',
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @import "./src/presentation/config/bootstrap/_custom.scss";
        `,
        silenceDeprecations: ['mixed-decls', 'legacy-js-api', 'color-functions', 'import', 'global-builtin']
      }
    }
  },
})

This error only appears in VS Code and the app continues to work. The problem is that the Swiper styles do not load completely, it can load some of the styles from 'swiper/css' but does not load the modules like 'swiper/css/thumbs'.
I've already tried restarting the TypeScript server and importing the minified modules. I've also tried to solve it in several other ways with ChatGPT but none of the solutions worked.
